# How big lens one has to have to concentrate moonlight so to feel the warmth?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, optics, lenses, estimation, moon

How big lens one has to use to concentrate moonlight so to feel the warmth?

Comment: What do you mean "to feel the warmth"? Why is it the *size* of the lens that would determine that?